# Journey Builder Decision Split CONTAINS Operator

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

My client wants to create a filter decision split within the journey in a field that contains 4000 characters, with the operator CONTAINS. The question is: whats is the efficiency of performing this operation when we are injecting around 2M of contacts? Will it work out well or is there any problem with processing of this much data?

Comment: Will you be manually injecting 2 millions contacts, simultaneously? is it just a single contain operator? Would you be able to handle this at the SQL layer instead, so that you could use the Equal to operator in the decision splits?

Comment: Yes, it would be injected simultaneosly, and would be a single decission split, where the idea is to find the keyword contained within the field. The idea of doing through sql is not good because the user dont have tech knowledge to perform a query, so, its possible to process this volume of data?

Comment: Any requirements on processing time?

Comment: Yes it would be a must to proccess the data asap, but from my knowledge i dont know how much it costs in terms of time... if anyone know or have tested the process would be very helpful..

Comment: Don't believe JB would work. Per IP, i believe marketing cloud sends out 2-3 million emails Per hour, 10-15 million with burst sending. And you are adding entry and decision splits on top of that